# Getting type of field (none instance)

Tags: c#, types, null, field, instance

Can I get the type of a field? `Type.GetType();` only returns the type of an instance, so if field is set `null` I cant get the Type.

Note: I would prefer not using reflections~

Comment: null isnt a type.. its a value. The field is still the same type regardless. You should check for null beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on context [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) and [PropertyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx) may work for you. I.e. if you have object type and property name:

```
var typeOfLength = typeof(String).GetProperty("Length").PropertyType;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you only want the compile time type when the field is null. A simple method like this could work:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static Type GetCompileTimeType<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return typeof(T);
    }
}
```

You could modify it it check for null and return the actual type if that is what you want.

usage:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

class C 
{
    private A a1, a2;
    public C()
    {
       a2 = new B();
       Console.WriteLine(a1.GetCompileTimeType()); // null but prints A
       Console.WriteLine(a2.GetCompileTimeType()); // actually a B but prints A
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test
{
    private int fTestInt;
    private string fTestString;
}
```

You can achieve getting the field type by typing `fTestInt.GetType()`.

If you want a quick type validation you can use.

```
if (fTestInt is int)
{
    Console.Write("I'm an int!");
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're asking.  Your question seems partial.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just ask if is null ?

```
if (Type != null)
{
    return Type.GetType().Name;
}
else
{
    return "";
}
```